# use of div tag with tabel-cell and row

Tags: css, html

[image]

I want to design above image with div only in HTML, i have tried with following code:

this css part

```
<style type="text/css">

    .divTable
    {

        border-color: Gray;
        border: 1px;
        border-spacing: 0.5px;
        border-style: solid;
        display: table;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 2px 1px 0px 1px;
         background-color: #CCCCCC;
    }
    .divRow
    {
      display: table-row;
      border-color: White;
        border: 1px;
        border-spacing: 0.5px;

        padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    }
        .divCell
        {
          display: table-cell;
             float: left;
            border-color: White;
        border: 2px;
        padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;


    }
</style>
```

this is html part

```
    <div class="divTable">
    <div class="divRow">
        <div class="divCell">
            <span>
                <label id="lblId">
                    ID</label></span>
        </div>
        <div class="divCell">
            <span>
                <label id="Label1">
                    Name</label></span>
        </div>
        <div class="divCell">
            <span>
                <label id="Label2">
                    Age</label></span>
        </div>
        <div class="divCell" >
            <span>
                <label id="Label3" >
                    Date Of Birth</label></span>
        </div>
        <div class="divCell">
            <span>
                <label id="Label4">
                    Gender</label></span>
        </div>
        <div class="divCell">
            <span>
                <label id="Label5" >
                    </label></span>
        </div>
        <div class="divCell"">
            <span>
                <label id="Label6">
                    Username</label></span>
        </div>
        <div class="divCell">
            <span>
                <label id="Label7">
                    Credential</label></span>
        </div>
        <div class="divCell">
            <span>
                <label id="Label8">
                    Company Name</label></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divRow">

    </div>
    <div class="divRow">

    </div>
    <div class="divRow">

    </div>
</div>
```

something is wrong with div cell how could i set them,please check the code and css and help me out to figure this,
Iwant to design the page with div only so on minimize maximize of page desighn will remain same

Comment: why not use a table instead? It's actually looks like a table!

Comment: @jingyinggong requirement is to do with div tag only no table plzzzzzzzzz help

Comment: @jing: it's not really a table, I'd argue for a `<dl>` personally, it just *looks* like a `<table>`; so I'd agree that a table shouldn't be used in this case.

Comment: why you want this to do with only div the design and structure is suitable for table ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display: block;` in `.divTable`. You only need `display: table;`.

Also in the `.divCell`, you may change `float: left` to `text-align: left;`

Comment: i  want to adjust this div when we minimize and maximize screen it should remain same how could we achive this...with display block it expand on complete page and with table it exapan according to the cell that im addin to it

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `display:table` by applying `display:block` remove `display:block`

Answer (score 0):

see this `jsfiddle` demo it is in `<table>` but when you minimize  maximize of page design will remain same

http://jsfiddle.net/jkkheni/D6VHG/

new fiddle link with div

http://jsfiddle.net/jkkheni/D6VHG/1/

Comment: hi thanks for your reply but i want it with div..plz help me out in this

Comment: hello @shweta please this new jsfiddle link i updated with div format

Comment: AND one mistake i found in your html struture it is small quote mistake <div class="divCell""> at parent of id=label6  @shweta

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. i made some modification

HTML

```
<div class="divTable">
        <div class="divRow">
            <div style="width:10%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-left:2px solid #fff">
            ID
            </div>

            <div style="width:10%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            Name
            </div>

            <div style="width:10%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            Age
            </div>

            <div style="width:10%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            Date of Birth
            </div>

            <div style="width:10%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            Gender
            </div>

            <div style="width:15%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            _
            </div>

            <div style="width:11%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            Username
            </div>

            <div style="width:11%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            Credential
            </div>

            <div style="width:11%; line-height:25px; float:left;">
            Company Name
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="divRow">
            <div style="line-height:25px; float:left; width:50%; border:2px solid #fff; border-right:none">
            Subject1
            </div>

            <div style="line-height:25px; float:left; width:49%; border:2px solid #fff;">
            Subject2
            </div>
        </div>

          <div class="divRow">
            <div style="line-height:25px; float:left; width:50%; border:2px solid #fff; border-top:none; border-right:none">
            Subject1
            </div>

            <div style="line-height:25px; float:left; width:49%; border:2px solid #fff; border-top:none">
            Subject2
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="divRow">
            <div style="width:9%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff; border-left:2px solid #fff">
            0000
            </div>

            <div style="width:9%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            1111
            </div>

            <div style="width:9%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            2222
            </div>

            <div style="width:9%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            -----
            </div>

            <div style="width:9%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            3333
            </div>

            <div style="width:9%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            4444
            </div>

            <div style="width:9%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            5555
            </div>

            <div style="width:9%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            6666
            </div>

            <div style="width:9%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            7777
            </div>

            <div style="width:9%; line-height:25px; float:left; border-right:2px solid #fff">
            8888
            </div>

             <div style="width:8%; line-height:25px; float:left;">
            9999
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
.divTable
    {

        border-color: Gray;
        border: 1px #fff;
        border-spacing: 0.5px;
        border-style: solid;
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 2px 1px 0px 1px;
         background-color: #CCCCCC;
    }
    .divRow
    {
      display: table-row;
      border:1px solid #fff;
      width:100%;
      position:relative;
      background:#ffcc00
    }

</style>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply but it structure changes as screen size changes :(

Comment: @shweta what screen size you want?? this will display fine in <=1360 resolution..

Comment: it display normal on maximize screen bt when i change the size structre of all div get displace

Comment: @shweta if you use div than you should be very clear for the size of div.. can't change the size to get same structure as you want

Comment: you can also use bootstrap for proper formatting of contents